# How do get data out Angular $scope.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using this as a starting point:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CncDWCktXTuBQdDVfuVv?p=preview

When one clicks on an item: `selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,` is filled with a item. How can the output of selectedItem be passed out of ng-model and into another js function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but if you want to run some code when the selection changes the easiest way to do that is to add a [watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch).

```
$scope.$watch('mySelections', function (value) {
    // Triggered every time mySelections is changed.
});
```

(I apologize if I totally misunderstood your question.)

**Update with example**

This is a simple example using the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service. The watch will trigger every time `$scope.mySelections` changes and the `value` parameter will reflect its value.

```
$scope.$watch('mySelections', function (value) {
    $http.post('/path/', { selectedItems: value })
       .success(function (result) {
            alert('Saved!');
        }).error(function (err) {
            alert(err);
    });
}, true);
```

Notice the third parameter with the value `true`. That one is needed for angular to notice changes in the array. (More about the third parameter [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch).)

Comment: Using something like angular seed. The js file is broken into two pieces. So, trying to pass selectedItems from one js file back to server.js, another js file.  Within one file,  'mySelections' output, into another js function. Using filter as model. Yes, this is not the right way to do it. BUT nevertheless, output of ng-model into another js function that would allow filtering.

Comment: @Merlin file vs file makes little sense to read, `angular seed` is set up with services, filters, directives etc as files. Using those as references would help, along with a better explanation of what you are trying to do with the results

Comment: @charlietfl: Using the plunker above, I would like to sumbit the selectedItems to a database. I have "app.post" setup but I need to get the selectedItem data out of $scope and into the function "app.post". If can get the data out of selectedItem as string or object, I should be able to the get the data into a database.

Comment: @Merlin  You will defintiely want to do what Martin suggests and watch `mySelections` and use `$http` or `$resource` to send AJAX update. You got things quite misleading with concept of multiple functions and files

Comment: @charlietfl, an example would be helpful.

Comment: @Martin, The code only fires on load, But not on changes to selectedItems.

Comment: @Merlin, a third parameter with the value `true` was needed for angular to notice the changes to the underlying array. Otherwise it's a reference equality and since it is the same array all the time angular doesn't notice the change. I've updated the example.

Comment: @Martin, here's the problem above code is in main.js. The database logic is server.js/app.js - the web server (express/nodejs). I was able to get a table from database into "$scope." Now reversing the path. I have "app.post ('/path/' function" setup to receive the "value". But I dont know how to get it there. I dont want to expose my database logic in main.js. TIA.